# Fix Intellij Idea download sources Connection Refused to host 127.0.0.1 error

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

When I try to download sources of a library class pulled by Maven I receive error in Intellij IDEA:

```
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1
```

Comment: What is your IDE version?

Comment: @Andrey 2021.1.1

Comment: This problem has been fixed for 2021.1.3 version: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-247792. Please try it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**UPD** (from @Andrey): This might have been fixed in version 2021.1.3

**For older versions:**

This can be fixed by selecting a proper JDK in your project's Maven Importer setting.

In the project setting go to Build Tools -> Maven -> Importing

Set JDK for importer to the JDK installed on your OS (Not the built-in one)

Try to download sources again - should be working now.

[image: fix download sources connection refused]

Comment: Works well! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

After setting JDK for the Maven importer to the installed JDK, if you have done the setting and still can not download sources, you may just need to re-open your project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Changing JDK for importer works
Settings> Build, Execution,Deployment>Build Tools>Maven>Importing
Change the "JDK for importer": [from Default to ] installed version of JDK
[image]